# Telegraf encounters a data overwriting problem when writing data

Tags: telegraf, cnosdb

When I write cpu and disk monitoring data to the same database, the result is normal. But when I write cpu and coinmarket data separately, there is an overwrite problem, is it a configuration file problem?
coinmarket:

```
+---------------------+--------+--------------------+------------------+--------------------------------+------------------------------+--------------------+----------------------+--------------------+--------------------+----------------------+------------------------------+------------------------------+--------------+------------------------------------+-----------------------------+------------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+----+-------------+
| time                | symbol | circulating_supply | num_market_pairs | quote_USD_market_cap_dominance | quote_USD_percent_change_30d | quote_USD_price    | quote_USD_volume_24h | cmc_rank           | max_supply         | quote_USD_market_cap | quote_USD_percent_change_24h | quote_USD_percent_change_90d | total_supply | quote_USD_fully_diluted_market_cap | quote_USD_percent_change_1h | quote_USD_percent_change_60d | quote_USD_percent_change_7d | quote_USD_volume_change_24h | id | platform_id |
+---------------------+--------+--------------------+------------------+--------------------------------+------------------------------+--------------------+----------------------+--------------------+--------------------+----------------------+------------------------------+------------------------------+--------------+------------------------------------+-----------------------------+------------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+----+-------------+
| 2023-06-25T06:36:10 | BTC    | 0.0                | 0.0              | 92.57425742615341              | 0.39603960393812454          | 0.1980198019735647 | 2.574257425404204    | 1.4851485147116863 | 2.7722772275578667 | 0.0                  | 0.0                          |                              |              |                                    |                             |                              |                             |                             |    |             |
+---------------------+--------+--------------------+------------------+--------------------------------+------------------------------+--------------------+----------------------+--------------------+--------------------+----------------------+------------------------------+------------------------------+--------------+------------------------------------+-----------------------------+------------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+----+-------------+.
```

cpu:

```
+---------------------+-----+------+-------------+-------------------+---------------------+---------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+------------+-----------+------------+
| time                | cpu | host | usage_guest | usage_guest_nice  | usage_idle          | usage_iowait        | usage_softirq      | usage_steal        | usage_system       | usage_user | usage_irq | usage_nice |
+---------------------+-----+------+-------------+-------------------+---------------------+---------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+------------+-----------+------------+
| 2023-06-25T06:36:10 |     |      | 0.0         | 92.15589541250097 | 0.3453379378453515  | 0.222002960053696   | 3.1080414406440586 | 1.5046867291551138 | 2.6640355207161424 | 0.0        | 0.0       |            |
| 2023-06-25T06:36:10 |     |      | 0.0         | 92.57425742615341 | 0.39603960393812454 | 0.1980198019735647  | 2.574257425404204  | 1.4851485147116863 | 2.7722772275578667 | 0.0        | 0.0       |            |
| 2023-06-25T06:36:10 |     |      | 0.0         | 91.84675834948064 | 0.19646365421603493 | 0.19646365421603493 | 3.4381139487627426 | 1.571709233585333  | 2.750491158953016  | 0.0        | 0.0       |            |
| 2023-06-25T06:36:10 |     |      | 0.0         | 92.48269039878733 | 0.3956478733702039  | 0.19782393669409792 | 2.868447082082412  | 1.5825914935527834 | 2.472799208622248  | 0.0        | 0.0       |            |
| 2023-06-25T06:36:10 |     |      | 0.0         | 91.81459566049588 | 0.49309664690664023 | 0.1972386587698316  | 3.550295857928724  | 1.3806706113529437 | 2.5641025640436883 | 0.0        | 0.0       |            |
+---------------------+-----+------+-------------+-------------------+---------------------+---------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+------------+-----------+------------+.
```

When I write to different databases separately, everything works fine.
telegraf config of coinmarket:

```
[global_tags]
  [agent]
    interval = "10s"
    round_interval = true
    metric_batch_size = 1000
    metric_buffer_limit = 10000
    collection_jitter = "0s"
    flush_interval = "10s"
    flush_jitter = "0s"
    precision = "0s"
    hostname = ""
    omit_hostname = false
  [[inputs.http]]
  urls = [
    "https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest?start=1&limit=10"
  ]
  method = "GET"
  headers = {"X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY" = "c4c8dfc6-0e84-4933-8ed2-88cfb18550be"}
  insecure_skip_verify = false
  data_format= "json"
  tagexclude=["url", "host"]
  json_query = "data"
  name_override = "coinmarketcap"
  tag_keys = ["symbol"]
  json_time_key = "last_updated"
  json_time_format = "RFC3339"
    [[outputs.http]]

url = "http://localhost:8902/api/v1/write?db=public"

  method = "POST"
  timeout = "5s"
  data_format = "influx"
  username = "root"
  password = ""
  influx_max_line_bytes = 250
```